Configuring incorrect password in Configuration manager when deploying the package
I have deployed an SSIS package in the Integration services catalog. In configuration manager, I have given a wrong password for connecting to source data in the password parameter. But still the SSIS job is running fine without failing for connection when its scheduled from a scheduler.
However its throwing connection error when I am manually running the package by providing a wrong password hardcoded in the package.
Note: Connection to source is made through ODBC driver.
I need to understand how the job is running fine when a incorrect password is provided in the deployed package.

Did you maybe parameterize the connection so it will pull the password from the value stored in your project/package parameters?

@Filburt Yes its parameterized, It will pull value from parameters in the package.
